# How to show in full hours, the result like this. 8hrs./30minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show the correct format and complete (8hrs/30mns)

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(Date1),MAX(Date1)) AS Daily Hours,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, MIN(Date1),MAX(Date2)) AS Daily Minutes,
TIMESTAMPDIFF
('Daily Minutes' / 60,) AS full hours
FROM Attendance
```

[see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0VQL.png)

Comment: Use your application programming language to handle presentation of data.

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345672/how-to-get-daily-hours-or-time-difference-like-this-result-from-timestampdiff), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71346229/i-need-to-show-difference-hours-from-timestamp-result-example-8hrs-30mns-ins) ? If you need to add more details, no need to open a new thread, just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71368110/edit) the question.

Comment: then? it will post as new post?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SET @from_time = '2022-01-01 01:02:03';
> SET @till_time = '2022-01-01 04:15:26';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @from_time time1,
>        @till_time time2,
>        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @from_time, @till_time) diff_in_sec,
>        SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @from_time, @till_time)) diff_as_time,
>        DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @from_time, @till_time)), '%hhrs./%imns') diff_formatted;
> ```
>
> | time1 | time2 | diff_in_sec | diff_as_time | diff_formatted |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-01-01 01:02:03 | 2022-01-01 04:15:26 | 11603 | 03:13:23 | 03hrs./13mns |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec88e4ea53857be5a8bea103c5647942)*